# Edit GTK theme in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, themes

How can I edit colors of current theme?
I have bright theme with white windows but I can see black tooltips when I move mouse above Firefox' tabs, or Eclipse IDE. That's what I'd change.

[image: Eclipse]

[image: Firefox]

Comment: Hi! You could edit `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`
 (after making a backup). Replace `Ambiance` with the name of your theme. In this file, change the hex values in `tooltip_fg_color:#555555\n` and `tooltip_bg_color:#000000\n` to whatever you like. Do note some software may use gtk-2.0 and others may use gtk-3.0. The hack is for those that use gtk-2.0.

Answer (score 2):

I found similar settings in the files listed below, but simply changing them, then changing theme to something else and then back to Ambiance in System **Settings** >**Appearance**> **Theme** flickers the screen but otherwise doesn't work for me. And I can't even see the copy of Ambience I created in the same directory to fiddle with. I'm going to try logging out, and if that doesn't work - rebooting.

`/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

`/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

It's unfortunate when programmers like Eclipse misuse system settings, and print in non-tooltip foreground on tooltip background, resulting on black-on-black.

I'm surprised there isn't a theme editor, linked from the 'Appearances' tab, that lets you tweak colours and then tells Gnome to refresh its idea about the themes -- without rebooting.

I like Ubuntu, but its UI quality seems to be slipping rapidly.

Comment: @penreturn please help I edited the setting.ini file and interchanged the tooltip_fg_color and tooltip_bg_color as I wanted text in black and background white as it's a problem reading text in eclipse (part of adt bundle) but the same problem persist. here's the screen shot http://postimg.org/image/b13vp4ebl/